# Is it possible to send a file from java applet to php without mysql?

Tags: java, php, applet, data-transfer

Is it possible send a image or file from an java applet to a php script which produce a pdf.

Until now my java applet has the opportunity that you can save a screenshot of the applet in the users chosen directory and the user can save the test results in form of a pdf. But I want t combine it to one file and I would like to avoid to work with a database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it wouldn't even make sense to use a database for this (unless that is the source of the test results). Just upload the screenshot/results as one POST request and then generate PDF with PHP.

Comment: Hmmmm.. until now I don't need a database. The test results are not stored in a database. So I would need the database only for the screenshots :(

Is there no other opportunity?

Comment: No, you don't need a database for the screenshots.  Why do you think you do?  Your PHP code receives the screenshot as POST data in the request and it sends the PDF as the response.  You're not *storing* the screenshots, right?

Comment: And if I have more pages with more than one java applet? What would be the easiest way to send the screenshots from form to form (like I do it with the content of the forms)?

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is to render the PDF combining both, the image and the test results right? The processing Framework has a nice Render2PDF function. Integrate it in your project and u wont need this PHP stuff which comes directly from hell.

Radek

Comment: But my test is in the php page in form of html tags and not part of the java applet.

Comment: You could parse it. There are lots of HTML Parsers out there. Search HTML parsing or rather scraping. Yeah I think thats the way to go here.